# RxSwift PublishSubject triggers unintentionally on initialization

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to use a PublishSubject to forward button clicks. However this PublishSubject triggers on initialisation and that interferes with my logic. This is what I'm doing:

```
var buttonClick = PublishSubject<Void>()
```

(This initialisation line will trigger the first Next event)

Then on the button tap action:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        buttonClick.onNext()
    }
```

and then I subscribe to it like this:

```
buttonClick
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
            .driveNext { () in

            }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Is there any way to do this without triggering the first "Next" event published upon initialisation?

Cheers!

Comment: can you simply use `rx_tap` button's method?

Comment: @MichałCiuba that's a much better solution yes! Thanks. However it still triggers the first unintended Next event. This is what I have now:`emptyStateView.button.rx_tap
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
            .driveNext { () in
                
            }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)`

Answer (score -1):

Ended up using `rx_tap` as suggested by @MichałCiuba.

About the unintended Next event, it turned out that it was just the breakpoint stopping multiple times for some reason, but the actual code was working as expected.